# __init__() got multiple values for argument 'test_size'

Tags: python

```
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(labels,10,test_size=0.2, random_state=23)

for train_index, test_index in sss:
    X_train, X_test = train.values[train_index], train.values[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = labels[train_index], labels[test_index]
```

earlier I used  sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedShuffleSplit . however it did't work. Then I tried from `sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit`, it throws below error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-340cc4ca20bc> in <module>()
----> 1 sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(labels,10,test_size=0.2, random_state=23)
      2 
      3 for train_index, test_index in sss:
      4     X_train, X_test = train.values[train_index], train.values[test_index]
      5     y_train, y_test = labels[train_index], labels[test_index]

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'test_size'
```

if test_size error recovered then remaining code will work

Comment: You're passing both `10` and `0.2` as values for `test_size`…

Answer (score 0):

In the line:
`sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(labels,10,test_size=0.2, random_state=23)`

You are passing multiple values in for the argument `test_size` (in this case, you are passing `10` and `0.2`).

Please read [the documentation on StratifiedShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) for more clarification. Maybe change that line to:

`sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(10, test_size=0.2, random_state=23)`